# R multiple errbar in the same plot

Tags: r, plot

is it possible to plot multiple errbar's in the same chart? 
So when Im doing this:

```
x <- c(5.7/6,5.723/6,5.678/6,5.7/6,5.8/6,5.75/6,5.789/6,5.987/6,5.978/6,5.998/6)
y <- c(15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150)

xplus <- x+runif(10,0.01,0.015)
xminus <- x-runif(10,0.01,0.015)

errbar(y,x, xplus,xminus,type="b",ylim=c(0,1), lwd=2,lty=1)
```

I want to add another errbar to it. So simply put another errbar does not work.
It overrides the previous one. Hope can I achieve this?

Comment: maybe call `par(new = T)` before calling the second `errbar`.

Comment: Ah im stupid. there is an option add in errbar which needs to be =TRUE. Then it works...

Comment: You can (and should) submit an answer for your own question in another hour or so ...